# ¿Agregar un objeto a una variable nula en JS?

Tags: javascript

Hola graicas por sus respuestas y comentarios acudo a ustedes por lo siguiente,tengo el sigeuinte array de objetos:

```
const customCatalogs = [
  customTableValues = [
    {id: 2, puestos: "Recursos Humanos", visible: "puesto dos"},
    {id: 1, puestos: "Dearrollador", visible: "puesto uno"}
  ],
  customEmployeeValue = null
];
```

Quiero agregar a customEmployeeValue el siguiente objeto:

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  puestos: "Dearrollador",
  visible: "puesto uno"
}
```

Pero estoy intentado agregar este objeto dentro de una clave con nombre value, quiero lograr esto:

```
   const customCatalogs = [
      customTableValues = [
        {id: 2, puestos: "Recursos Humanos", visible: "puesto dos"},
        {id: 1, puestos: "Dearrollador", visible: "puesto uno"}
      ],
      customEmployeeValue = {
        value: {
          id: 1,
          puestos: "Dearrollador",
          visible: "puesto uno"
      }
      }
    ];
```

**Donde el obeto que quiero añadir tiene la clave value**.

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```js
   
const payload = {
          id: 1,
          puestos: "Dearrollador",
          visible: "puesto uno"
      };

const customCatalogs = [
      customTableValues = [
        {id: 2, puestos: "Recursos Humanos", visible: "puesto dos"},
        {id: 1, puestos: "Dearrollador", visible: "puesto uno"}
      ],
      customEmployeeValue = null
    ];

customCatalogs.customEmployeeValue = payload;

console.log(customCatalogs)
```

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas y comentarios.

Comment: Enterado cuando eleimines tu comentario elimino el mío gracias por la correción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que está mal definida la estructura, basado en tu idea de manejar un array de objetos, tendrías que arreglar la estructura y acceder al índice 1 del array para poder acceder al objeto cuyo key es "customEmployeeValue".

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
const payload = {
    id: 1,
    puestos: "Dearrollador",
    visible: "puesto uno"
};

const customCatalogs = [
{customTableValues: [
  {id: 2, puestos: "Recursos Humanos", visible: "puesto dos"},
  {id: 1, puestos: "Dearrollador", visible: "puesto uno"}
]},
{customEmployeeValue: null}
];

customCatalogs[1].customEmployeeValue = payload;

console.log(customCatalogs)
```

---

Otra forma es no utilizar un array y hacer todo con objeto. De la siguiente manera:

```
const payload = {
  id: 1,
  puestos: "Dearrollador",
  visible: "puesto uno",
};

const customCatalogs = {
  customTableValues: [
    { id: 2, puestos: "Recursos Humanos", visible: "puesto dos" },
    { id: 1, puestos: "Dearrollador", visible: "puesto uno" },
  ],
  customEmployeeValue: null,
};

customCatalogs.customEmployeeValue = payload;

console.log(customCatalogs);
```